# Monitoring server file systems from a Zabbix agent in a container?

Tags: docker, zabbix

I recently noticed that the file systems automatically discovered on a server I was monitoring made no sense and looked like regular files..

After banging my head a bit, I realized it was because the Zabbix Agent on that server is run inside a container, and the file systems it is listing are the file systems that container can see, including docker file mounts!  This of course defeats the purpose of monitoring that server..

I think of a couple of options, neither satisfactory:

• I can explicitly mount some of the server file systems for the agent to discover and correctly monitor, but now I have to keep this up to date
• I can run the agent directly on the server, but the container route seems so clean..

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and you just made me realize it's related to the dockerized agent. Someone seems to have [found a working solution using `priviledged` and "host" `pid`](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/issues/177#issuecomment-367308731) but that doesn't do anything for me. That's also what seems to be [suggested on the official repo](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/blob/6.0/docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_mysql_latest.yaml#L278). Interested to know if that works for anyone though

Comment: I tried using:   pid: host
    privileged: true
    volumes:
     - /sys:/sys
     - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup. but I still don't get the proper filesystems from inside the container..